# Transform Between Uniform Distributions

Tags: integration, probability-theory, random-variables, recreational-mathematics

Let $c\in[0,1]^2$ and $f_c: [0,1]^2\to[0,1]$ be defined as follows:

Given $u\in[0,1]^2\neq c$, let $d$ be the positive scalar such that $c+d(u-c)$ lies on the border of $[0,1]^2$.  Then define $f(u):=(1/d)^2$ and $f(c):=0$.  So the function on a single line from $c$ to the border of $[0,1]^2$ is just $x^2$ scaled down so it runs from $0$ to $1$.

[image]

My question: does $f$ transform $[0,1]^2$-uniformly distributed random variables into $[0,1]$-uniformly distributed random variables?  In other words, do we have $\lambda(f_c^{-1}([a,b]))=b-a?$

My intuition is yes, I imagine $[0,1]^2$ to be sliced in thin triangles starting in $c$.  So on each triangle, the thickness linearly scales with distance from $c$, so I want the derivative of my density function along the triangle to equal a multiple of $1/x$ and also go from $0$ to $1$.  The square term seems to satisfy this.

Is this thinking correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

Define $l(\theta)$ to be the length of the line between $c$ and the border of $[0, 1]^2$, at an angle $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$. If we make a transformation to scaled polar co-ordinates about $c$,

$$x = c + r l(\theta) \cos(\theta),\qquad y = c + r l(\theta) \sin(\theta),$$

then the random variables $R \in [0, 1]$ and $\Theta \in [0, 2\pi]$ have joint density $$f(r, \theta) = f(x, y)\ \bigg\lvert\frac{d(x,y)}{d(r,\theta)}\bigg\rvert = rl(\theta)^2,$$ so $R \sim \text{Beta(2, 1)}$ independent of $\Theta$, with density $f(r) = 2r$.

Then letting $s = r^2 = 1/d^2$, the density of $S \in [0,1]$ is
$$f(s) = f(r)\ \bigg\lvert\frac{dr}{ds}\bigg\rvert = 1,$$
as required.